# more than one vote for single as well as guest users

Tags: 7, polls

I am using Drupal 7 with my custom theme. I have enabled core poll module and create poll form content and it will display on my desire place. but when any one can vote it will display result this flow was correct.

I want to do that when any one can vote than after display result but when refresh page or when ever come to that page it will display question and choices instead of result display. means I want that user or guest will give vote no. of times.

Is it possible with core poll module?

Thanks.

Comment: what would be a use case for the same? why would you want to allow people to cast more than one vote?

Comment: because guest user give vote at one time and after that no one can give vote. and my client wants that any one can vote more than one time but not more than  5 times.

Comment: The guest user from the same system will not be able to vote again. If they are on different IP then they can definitely vote. Any way to make a work around on that please use the poll Enhancement module http://drupal.org/project/pollanon

Comment: Thanks for quick replay  I have already use this module but no luck. any other way?